# ¡ǝƃuǝןןɐɥɔ uʍop ǝpısdn

Tags: code-golf

Turn the characters `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!?.,` upside down and don't modify the other characters. Then, reverse the text to achieve the upside down affect. If text is already upside down, turn it right side up. Don't modify capitals.

Use this as a reference:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!?.,
ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞןɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz¡¿˙'
```

### Rules

- Newlines must be supported
- You only have to convert the above character set.
- **Don't forget you need to reverse the characters.**
- This question is symmetrical unlike Small Caps Converter.

### Test cases

```
42 is the meaning of life -> ǝɟıן ɟo ƃuıuɐǝɯ ǝɥʇ sı 24
halp why is my keyboard typing upside down??? :( -> (: ¿¿¿uʍop ǝpısdn ƃuıdʎʇ pɹɐoqʎǝʞ ʎɯ sı ʎɥʍ dןɐɥ
lol -> ןoן
uoɥʇʎpʎzɐɹc -> ɔrazydython
```

<sup><sub>Look at my username!</sub></sup>

Comment: Your last test case breaks "don't modify capitals".

Comment: @Geobits I told myself to fix that later but then I forgot. Silly me!

Comment: Your... last testcase... breaks... ***Don't modify capitals.***

Comment: Would this qualify as [tag:kolomorgov-complexity]?

Comment: @LeakyNun I should proofread my challenges...

Comment: Isn't this too similar to [Sᴍᴀʟʟ Cᴀᴘꜱ Cᴏɴᴠᴇʀᴛᴇʀ](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60443/s%e1%b4%8d%e1%b4%80%ca%9f%ca%9f-c%e1%b4%80%e1%b4%98%ea%9c%b1-c%e1%b4%8f%c9%b4%e1%b4%a0%e1%b4%87%ca%80%e1%b4%9b%e1%b4%87%ca%80)?

Comment: @manatwork You have to reverse the characters too.

Comment: None of your test cases have lines breaks or mixed (some right-side-up, some upside-down)

Comment: Not another question on the brink of closing....

Comment: Many solutions below can be improved by removing o, s, x, and z from the LUTs.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 78 bytes

I need to use an actual byte counter more often

```
->s{s.reverse.tr'a-z!?.,',"ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞןɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz¡¿˙'"}
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/C1Yf)

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Comment: It would be 78 bytes, lol. `2D 3E 73 7B 73 2E 72 65 76 65 72 73 65 2E 74 72
27 61 2D 7A 21 3F 2E 2C 27 2C 22 C9 90 71 C9 94
70 C7 9D C9 9F C6 83 C9 A5 C4 B1 C9 BE CA 9E D7
9F C9 AF 75 6F 64 62 C9 B9 73 CA 87 6E CA 8C CA
8D 78 CA 8E 7A C2 A1 C2 BF CB 99 27 22 7D`

Comment: @Adnan, fixed the byte count

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny, was the problem characters vs bytes?

Comment: @SolomonUcko if you're talking about my comment about needing to use a byte counter, yes. This had 59 characters which tied with Pyth's byte count, so I was bragging about tying with Pyth even though my bytecount wasn't actually the same

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 73 bytes (54 chars)

Translate the chars, then reverse the input. I was pretty confused while making this until I realized some of the chars need to be escaped.

```
T`ɐqɔ\pǝɟƃɥıɾʞןɯu\o\dbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz¡¿˙'l!?.,`l!?.,o
O$^s`.
```

[**Try it online!**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGDJkHHJlFxwx53Jn8aDyaXEscm-yp7Xn8mvdVxvXGRiyblzyoduyozKjXjKjnrCocK_y5knbCE_LixgbCE_LixvCk8kXnNgLg&input=NDIgaXMgdGhlIG1lYW5pbmcgb2YgbGlmZQo8LT4Kx53Jn8Sx158gyZ9vIMaDdcSxdcmQx53JryDHncmlyocgc8SxIDI0)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 59 bytes

```
X_z+G"!?.,'˙¿¡zʎxʍʌnʇsɹbdouɯןʞɾıɥƃɟǝpɔqɐ
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=X_z%2BG%22%21%3F.%2C%27%CB%99%C2%BF%C2%A1z%CA%8Ex%CA%8D%CA%8Cn%CA%87s%C9%B9bdou%C9%AF%D7%9F%CA%9E%C9%BE%C4%B1%C9%A5%C6%83%C9%9F%C7%9Dp%C9%94q%C9%90&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=42+is+the+meaning+of+life%0Ahalp+why+is+my+keyboard+typing+upside+down%3F%3F%3F+%3A%28%0Alol%0Auo%C9%A5%CA%87%CA%8Ep%CA%8Ez%C9%90%C9%B9c&debug=0)

Obligatory hexdump:

```
58 5F 7A 2B 47 22 21 3F 2E 2C 27 CB 99 C2 BF C2
A1 7A CA 8E 78 CA 8D CA 8C 6E CA 87 73 C9 B9 62
64 6F 75 C9 AF D7 9F CA 9E C9 BE C4 B1 C9 A5 C6
83 C9 9F C7 9D 70 C9 94 71 C9 90
```

Comment: That was golfed quite a bit.

Comment: Damn and I thought I  was in with a chance when this first landed :P

Comment: Yeah, it was embarrassing.

Comment: might `."` work? or are they at far away code points?

Comment: @Maltysen `."` only works when the code-points of each character is similar. In this case, the code-points from inverted `z` to inverted `a` are: `[122, 654, 120, 653, 652, 110, 647, 115, 633, 98, 100, 111, 117, 623, 1503, 670, 638, 305, 613, 387, 607, 477, 112, 596, 113, 592]`.

Comment: @LeakyNun ok. wonder why unicode does this

Comment: @Maltysen `z`, `x`, `s`, `o` are preserved; `n` and `u` are swapped; `b` and `q` are swapped; `d` and `p` are swapped; inverted `y`, `w`, `v` belong to IPA, and stuff.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 3, 144 bytes

Don't work in the Windows terminal...

```
print(''.join([dict(zip("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!?.,","ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞןɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz¡¿˙'")).get(x,x)for x in input()[::-1]]))
```

Comment: This can be heavily golfed.

Comment: @LeakyNun I know, the vars were for debugging purpose...

Comment: Then you can remove them now. `reversed` can be replaced by `[::-1]`. Converting it to a lambda may save some bytes.

Comment: @LeakyNun Thank you !

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny It's for python 2 or 3 ? Because on my python 3 installation it throw a error

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny `ValueError: the first two maketrans arguments must have equal length` maketrans probably don't work with unicode...

Comment: Another thing you can do to save on code since `str.translate` isn't working: call `dict` on your zipped values instead of building the dictionary manually like you do.

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny Thanks you !

Comment: Also, https://repl.it/languages/python3 supports your code so it works on more than just IDLE.

Comment: Why did you revert to the older version? The `dict` solution still works https://repl.it/C1Zt

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny i don't know why it have been reverted, i fix it

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 140 bytes

```js
f=
s=>[...s].map(c=>r=((i=u.indexOf(c)+26)<26?c:u[i%52])+r,r="",u="abcdefghijklmnpqrtuvwy!?.,ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞןɯudbɹʇnʌʍʎ¡¿˙'")&&r
;
```

```html
<input oninput=o.value=f(this.value)><input id=o style=text-align:right>
```

Edit: Saved 8 bytes thanks to @Dúthomhas.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 88 bytes

**78 bytes code + 10 for `-Mutf8 -n`**

```pl
y/a-z!?.,/ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥıɾʞןɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz¡¿˙'/;print reverse/./g
```

#### Usage

Save as upsidedown.pl and run:

```pl
perl -Mutf8 -n upsidedown.pl <<< '42 is the meaning of life'
ǝɟıן ɟo ƃuıuɐǝɯ ǝɥʇ sı 24
```