#   

Tags: code-golf, unicode

## Introduction

Try to convert words to two different unicode fonts.

## Challenge

Your task is to transform your input string into the   and    unicode characters.

All uppercase words should become lowercase    words.

- For Example: `WORD` ->

All lowercase words should become   words

- For example: `other words` ->

All mixed case words should remain unchanged

- For example: `Mixed Case Words` -> `Mixed Case Words`

Periods and spaces should remain unchanged.

Words are separated by spaces or periods

- For example (highlighted things are words):

> `Hello`. `This` `is` `a` `word`. `S`.`O`. `are` `these`

- Inputs: A string containing letters, spaces, and periods (`[A-Za-z .]+`)
- Output: The formatted string

As this is a golfing challenge, the lowest number of bytes wins

## Example Input and Output

Input:

> This is an example STRING that c.o.U.L.d. be INPUTTED. It can CONTAIN multiple sentences.

Output:

> This      .....  . It    .

## Reference

Math Sans Bold:  (characters 120302 through 120327)

Math Sans:  (characters 120250 through 120275)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: ♫ Philosophy's just [ ](https://xkcd.com/1052/) rigor, sense, and practicality... ♫

Comment: Whoa! You got a title in bold in the sidebar? What? I... don't understand.... is the internet breaking? Have **you** broken the internet?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4V3C.png I came here thinking this challenge was about stacking boxes, bar charts or something...

Comment: This shouldn't have been close hammered. This problem is significantly more difficult than a simple character transliteration. The [leading answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92478/31957) in the cited challenge can not easily nor competitively be transferred using that same method (afaict, my retina isn't great)

Answer (score 10):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), <s>45</s> 43 bytes

-2 thanks to ngn.

```apl
\w+
⎕UCS a+(2>≢b)×120153+84×⊃b←∪96>a←⎕UCS⍵M
```

Since TIO scrambles Unicode output from QuadR, here is a screenshot of using QuadR as an APL library in an interactive session:
[image: interactive session transcript]

---

`\w+` replace words with the result of applying the following code to them:

`⍵M` the found word

`⎕UCS` the **U**niversal **C**haracter **S**et code points of that

`a←` store that in `a`

`96>` 0 or 1 for whether 96 is greater than each of those

`∪` take just the unique; `[0]` or `[1]` or `[0,1]` or `[1,0]`

`b←` store that in `b`

`⊃` pick the first from that

`84×` multiply 84 with that

`120153+` add 120153 to that

`(`…`)×` multiply the following with that:

 `≢b` the tally (length) of `b` (`1` if single-case, `2` if mixed-case)

 `2>` 0 or 1 for whether two is greater than that (`1` if single-case, `0` if mixed-case)

`a+` the original code points added to that

`⎕UCS` convert the resulting code points back to characters

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>63</s> <s>57</s> 53 bytes

-6 thanks to Erik the Outgolfer. -4 thanks to ngn.

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
'\w+'⎕R{⎕UCS a+(2>≢b)×120153+84×⊃b←∪96>a←⎕UCS⍵.Match}
```

Since TIO scrambles Unicode output from Dyalog APL, here is a screenshot of the code in action:

[image: code in action]

---

`'\w+'⎕R` PCRE **R**eplace words with the result of applying the following…

`{`...`}` anonymous lambda:

`⍵.Match` the found word

`⎕UCS` the **U**niversal **C**haracter **S**et code points of that

`a←` store that in `a`

`96>` 0 or 1 for whether 96 is greater than each of those

`∪` take just the unique; `[0]` or `[1]` or `[0,1]` or `[1,0]`

`b←` store that in `b`

`⊃` pick the first from that

`84×` multiply 84 with that

`120153+` add 120153 to that

`(`…`)×` multiply the following with that:

`≢b` the tally (length) of `b` (`1` if single-case, `2` if mixed-case)

`2>` 0 or 1 for whether two is greater than that (`1` if single-case, `0` if mixed-case)

`a+` the original code points added to that

`⎕UCS` convert the resulting code points back to characters

Comment: 57 bytes: `'\b([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)\b'⎕R{⎕UCS(⎕UCS+120153+84×∊∘⎕A)⍵.Match}`

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thanks. Why didn't I think of going tacit‽

Comment: I don't know, but it happens to me when I'm tired. :)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Actually, I think I wrote this one from home using my wife's computer without APL keyboard layout…

Comment: @Adám that regex is too long; you're better off using `\w+` and computing the amount to add to the codepoints in the dfn: `'\w+'⎕R{⎕UCS a+(2>≢b)×120153+84×⊃b←∪96>a←⎕UCS⍵.Match}`

Comment: @ngn Separate answer-worthy?

Comment: @Adám I can't decide which is worth less: wasting some minutes of my life on explanations, or the potential for 9 upvotes :)

Comment: @ngn I'll explain if you want.

Comment: @ngn Btw, it is -2 for QuadR too.

Comment: @Adám go ahead then :) no need to credit - people can see my comments anyway

Comment: @ngn Comments are temporary, credit is forever!

Answer (score 8):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>268</s> <s>265</s> <s>232</s> 224 bytes

As a neat bonus, this works with strings containing *any* character. [Including nulls.](https://tio.run/##bVPbbtswDH3XVxBdgMao47i7AEUR994OAYKsWJynOkAUWa61yZIn0V0M7NuXyZesLdoHXchDnkOKNpOcql2h00pyKKhQO1GU2iAsMJ2Jje@OqcLmuNJa@jHfYrBUgumUvzKC5XVODakiYZdlyQ2R7nYpy5ySAfsjgUWZ0YWjGqJ2O7Cj44/h8ZdPRyIbVsC8k88QehEj5w@5b09xFT20QD45E3amf3MD1hsOmMeShE1GfdCqCXehg3xFLmz0UCfJdjJ6NLoqr@phQmETSaCR2zae9evJCM63q32Dr6q/Ve4Q6tEGy/juhIzHQDf6iUNWKYZCKwupVocIhv@qhOGAubDQEfkg8NDCj8oiVJangBqwMgoorBdoHOkahHJOZzfk8MbZO1pV5fLzZ10ojX4SqWPVStagOE/tc0Ybvm5ffu2D0tgprEnz1s0E7xxNXyboht@KQkhqZO33Ldj/NRf0J2@1U2FLSWsnAJxa4WZJstPTYac5OmsUPJK18@x8hKDDG//orPN4BCPUe3SB1CD5ALa1IYKD2GknYbOoSkK@pUUpeRIu4u/T@dckxJxiErJAB8tgFqRBEm4cOp3fL@P49saZ0wZuUq@/zePL6TwJi0qiaEksV8gV4zY4eKnpvrt@2KAh8/aAe5O2cYHQwy@TLvrra6KGwDXfx79HVToH0o3kJNozjMdvU501cOvdynZ/WSbpo92NprPdTa1oIVhn3EuKmTZFa3S/6T8)

```
import StdLib,StdInt,StdBool,Text.Unicode,Text.Unicode.UChar
u=isUpper
l=isAlpha
$c|l c=fromInt(toInt c+120153+if(u c)84 0)=c
?[h,s:t]=[if(u h<>isLower s)($c)c\\c<-[h,s:t]]
?[h]=[$h]
@s=[y\\x<-groupBy(\a b=l a&&l b)s,y<- ?x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVNtb9owEP7uX3HqUEvUENq9SBUi9L0TEmLVCJ8ACeM4jTfHzmynI9J@@9jlhbWo/ZDY99zd89z5bCY5VbtMx4XkkFGhdiLLtXEwc/FEbHxcxspVy43W0o/41gVzJZiO@YERzG9TakgRCjvPc26IxN21zFNKOuyPBBYmRmdI1XUa/8BOzz@enX/5dCqSbgHMu/gMZ17IyOUi9e3ArcJF7UiHI2En@jc3YL1uh3lsuWTDXhu0qsIxtJOuyJUNF@VyuR32nowu8puyu6SwCSXQ42MJG8/65bAHl9vVvsGD6u8VLkI92WAePVyQfh/oRj9zSArFnNDKQqzViQPDfxXCcHCpsNAQ@SDciYUfhXVQWB6D0@AKo4DCeuYMkq5BKATRrsjhDdgCtarC/PRFF3Kjn0WMrFrJEhTnsX3JqMPX9cmvfVDaNQprUp11NcEHpGnLBF3xW5EJSY0s/bYF@7/mjP7ktXYsbC5piQLAqRU4S5IMBt1GszeqFDyS1PNsMEIc@iu8N2oQj7jQ6b135qhx5APY2oYQjqJWmyrgW5rlePdm0ffx9CsWQPFyBDqYB5MgDmDDYTx9nEfR/V0AY3Rhyu23aXQ9nkJWSCeqXMuV44pxGxy9lsGr1s4XNCTe3oHHUPcqHLTu10lX7faQqCLAftv496hyBBzdSE7CPUO//zYVrQ5@71a2@8sSSZ/srjee7O5KRTPBGuNRUpdok9VG8zL/AQ)

Defines the function `@`, taking a `UString` and returning a `UString`

Comment: Is it also a clean bonus? :D

Answer (score 6):

## C, 292 characters, 448 bytes (in UTF-8)

```c
char*t;s,i,k;p(l){for(l=s=*t/96,i=k=strlen(t);i--;)t[i]/96-s&&++l;for(l=l-s&&write(1,t,k);!l&++i<k;)write(1,s?""+t[i]*4-388:""+t[i]*4-260,4);}f(char*s){char b[strlen(s)];for(t=b;*s;++s)*s<47?(*t=0),p(t=b),putchar(*s):(*t++=*s);*t=0;p(t=b);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PdDLTttAFAbgfZ5i8CKa8Q1oI0gzsRACVEVCoWqdVZSF4zrNyI6JMoNAiiK1QKH3llbC3uQVKJRLW@jllXiD8DsBLH8a2@ccz6/xrRe@Pxr5ba@nKy5NYYa8SyPWb633aORIR1fTj@ZM4YSOVL0oiKliXFgWZ6ouGihZMp83jIhP@qPsdbMnVEBnTWWGjE9FKItyyNndZ7mgXQ8PL@EK/sBf@Af/r4fJS3gF27ADu/Aa9mAf3sBbeAfv4QN8hE/wGb7AAXyFb5qRpdQL1sNisYRdkyP4DsdwAj/gFM7gHC7gJ/yC34CUCVImSJkgZYKUCVKmSJkiZYqUKVKmSJkiZYqU6f79rg/mZswC44MWHZ@vZP1sJc367VFK1hifm3KaXJfcMCTTZbkwv0B15cwws5tVsGyobI7iByVUDMPBE89a@KSDD0YiVqTjiZiyXD9HcLWo5raFJLi9mARbXqcbBeSZ@7RSfUxU21PEt9ftmr1qP7dJMyCV6pOa664s26SCEkaW1qruYqVKOhuREtmsDGIVxH4gbY3x3GB0Aw)

**Unrolled:**

```c
char*t;
s,i,k;

p(l)
{
    for (l=s=*t/96, i=k=strlen(t); i--;)
        t[i]/96-s && ++l;

    for (l=l-s&&write(1, t, k); !l&++i<k;)
        write(1, s ? ""+t[i]*4-388
                   : ""+t[i]*4-260, 4);
}

f(char*s)
{
    char b[strlen(s)];

    for (t=b; *s; ++s)
        *s<47 ? (*t=0), p(t=b), putchar(*s) : (*t++=*s);

    *t = 0;
    p(t=b);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>221</s> <s>219</s> <s>203</s> 201 bytes

```java
s->{StringBuffer r=new StringBuffer();for(String x:s.split("(?<=[\\. ])|(?=[\\. ])"))x.codePoints().forEach(c->r.appendCodePoint(c+(x.matches("[A-Z]+")?120237:x.matches("[a-z]+")?120153:0)));return r;}
```

I have to use a `StringBuffer` instead of a regular `String` to use `.appendCodePoint`, unfortunately..

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZJvS8MwEMbf71McfZUgDZtDhNVt6CYy0Dq0MnDbiyzNbGablCTV@qefvWbYgnujQgg5fvfc3XNkR1@or3Iud/FzzVJqDNxQIT86AEJarreUcQj3IcC91UI@XRTbLdfA0HcIBgeOVh13GUutYBCChCHUxh99HEj0UPLXgyoIB1ul20rlwBCTp8IiD43PhsvVisAaf6Jx@/QwLglTMZ8rN5xBmDj1JWUJYv5IE5o7H/Gk5YgdoZJk1LKEG@Qtz/3H9ZGHx73j7nH/dPATUf@9Rb2T/qCLMQ40t4WWoIOqDvbm8mKTOnONxxclYsjcpprhl2uKmy29GcszogpLckdsKpEkDHmL27upMxD8mqRs4hb1qnRs/sy9ESWPYUINh8W/BFEiDLhDJfCSZnnK4T66m4VXYBNqgRFFHsg1iQlsOMzC@UMUXU4JzBxyksltGJ3PQsiK1Iq91nD3QSTjhjSdq05VfwE)

```java
s->{                           // Method with String parameter and StringBuffer return-type
  StringBuffer r=new StringBuffer();
                               //  Resulting StringBuffer
  for(String x:s.split("(?<=[\\. ])|(?=[\\. ])"))
                               //  Split by space or dot, and keep them as separate items,
                               //  and loop over all those substrings
   x.codePoints().forEach(c->  //   Inner loop over the codepoints of that substring
      r.appendCodePoint(       //    Convert int to char, and append it to the result:
        c                      //     The next codepoint of the substring
        +(x.matches("[A-Z]+")? //     If the word is fully uppercase:
           120237              //      Add 120237 to convert it to Math Sans Bold
          :x.matches("[a-z]+")?//     Else-if the word is fully lowercase:
           120153              //      Add 120153 to convert it to Math Sans
          :                    //     Else (mixed case, or a dot/space)
           0)));               //      Leave the codepoint (and thus the character) as is
  return r;}                   //  Return the resulting StringBuffer
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>172</s> 170 bytes

```
(s#w)r=[x|all(`elem`s)w,c<-w,(x,k)<-zip r s,c==k]
t[]=[]
t w=filter(>[])[['A'..'Z']#w$[''..],['a'..'z']#w$[''..],w]!!0
f s|(a,b:c)<-span(>'.')s=t a++b:f c|1>0=t s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1LasMwGIT3OcWfB8gmiki3ITKEthRDcEvjbCoEkVUZG8uusRRkgs/RrnqFHqCn6g1cpYvCwDDfMEwhTKW0HsfAzF3YUdYPQuvgpLSqTyZ0WG5XDgc9rsLt6lK20IHBktKKTyzjlHkDR/NSW9UFEeMhY2iHCEEviM/dgqGfz48vnzlmSFz55Z@/f/9xx6fT9SQHMwQCZxvpf0wrmiBCBIWGWhDLZbbJQQ430dpHM9aibIBCe7YH2@0bWEAOs7QoDXiJBlQv6lYrOKTPcfIAthAWJHkjR7InrwQyBXHydEzT@zsCsa/85PYxSXdxAvVZ2/K6NaqxqpHKkNn4Cw)

Fairly straightforward. The `#` operator takes the set `s` of charcters (upper or lower case) the word `w`, and the math sans set `r`. It returns the word in the math sans font if all the characters in the word are in `s` or the empty list otherwise. The `t` function takes a word and tries all three possiblities (all upper, all lower, or mixed), returning the first one that isn't empty. The `f` function finds the first word by using `span`, transforming it with `t` and concatenating it with the separator (either `.` or space) and recurring on the rest of the string. The alternate case is for if span can't find a separator; we just transform the string.

Edit: Thanks to @Laikoni for taking off 2 bytes! I'm not used to the whole "operator that takes three arguments" thing

Comment: `(['A'..'Z']#w)[''..]` can be `['A'..'Z']#w$[''..]`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 34 bytes

```
e€ØBŒg
ṁÇµŒl,Œuiị“¡ẓƬ“¡ẓġ“’×Ç+OỌµ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/1UdOawzOcjk5K53q4s/Fw@6GtRyfl6BydVJr5cHf3o4Y5hxY@3DX52BoY68hCIOtRw8zD0w@3a/s/3N1zaCvQgP///4dkZBYrAFFinkJqRWJuQU6qQnBIkKefu0JJRmKJQrJevl6ono9eip5CUqqCp19AaEiIq4uegidQCqjF2d8vxNHTTyG3NKckE6S3ODWvJDUvObVYDwA)

Full program.

Comment: It's probably obvious to professional Jellyists, but could you add a brief explanation to show ẇƬƒ is going on here?

Comment: @MickMnemonic sorry, right now I don't have time to

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>34</s> <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

Includes an unprintable (charcode 153) after the last `#`.

```
rV="%b%A+%b"Èc+#x#í
rVv Èc+#x#
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=clY9IiViJUErJWIiyGMrI3gj7QpyVnYgyGMrI3gjmQ==&input=IlRoaXMgaXMgYW4gZXhhbXBsZSBTVFJJTkcgdGhhdCBjLm8uVS5MLmQuIGJlIElOUFVUVEVELiBJdCBjYW4gQ09OVEFJTiBtdWx0aXBsZSBzZW50ZW5jZXMuIg==)

---

### Explanation

```
                        :Implicit input of string U
r                       :Replace
   "%b%A+%b"            :/\b[A-Z]+\b/g
 V=                     :Assign ^that to variable V
            È           :Run each match through a function
             c          :Map over the codepoints of the current match
              +#x#í     :  Add 120237
\n                      :Assign the result of that replacement to variable U
rVv                     :Another replacement, this time with V lowercased to give us the RegEx /\b[a-z]+\b/g
    Èc+#x#              :And, again, map over the codepoints of each match, this time adding 120153 to each
```

---

### Original 32 Byte Japt v2 Solution

```
r/\b(\A+|\a+)\b/Èc_+#x#+#T*(X¶u
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ci9cYihcQSt8XGErKVxiL8hjXysjeCOZKyNUKihYtnU=&input=IlRoaXMgaXMgYW4gZXhhbXBsZSBTVFJJTkcgdGhhdCBjLm8uVS5MLmQuIGJlIElOUFVUVEVELiBJdCBjYW4gQ09OVEFJTiBtdWx0aXBsZSBzZW50ZW5jZXMuIg==)

```
r                                     :Replace
 /\b(\A+|\a+)\b/                      :...all matches of this RegEx (\A=[A-Z], \a=[a-z])
                È                     :Pass each match through a function, with X being the current match
                 c_                   :Pass the codepoints of X through a function
                   +                  :Add to the current codepoint
                    #x#               :120153 (there's an unprintable after the second #)
                        +#T           :Plus 84
                           *          :  Multiplied by
                            (X¶u      :  Is X equal to its uppercase self
```

Comment: Mind adding an XXD dump?

Comment: A reversible hexdump? For the unprintables.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>173</s> <s>122</s> 120 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join(chr(ord(c)+120153*t.islower()+120237*t.isupper())for t in re.split(r'\b(\w+)\b',s)for c in t)
import re
```

-51 bytes from ShreevatsaR

-2 bytes from abccd

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hc4xa8MwEIbhOfoVt1lqimhiSiDQwaUuHZqmYI9eZFnGKrIkTmec/HrX8XgvDx8X7zQEny/9W7M4NbadgnTOMvkXrOd6QB6w41rsD8eXw2v@RNImF2aDfEvH/LSlKcZHEn1AILAe0MgUnSWOWdPyZt6Lps2e0wb0A5BgdowBaaUL4f3MdvNgnYEaJ7Meu4jWE@@59XGidVowc9MmEpTXzxIx4IqiSmnZ3tEqGRgVDZCUT@z9@v0Bl6L@gqr4qdjF3kwHm6nLqma/k9c0KbLBSygqCbNxTv4D)

Splits on word boundaries (`re.split(r'\b(\w+)\b',s)`), then maps lowercase words to    (`+120153*t.islower()`), and uppercase words to    (`+120237*t.isupper()`), and leaves mixed-case words alone, then `join`s the words back up.

Ungolfed and un-lambda-ed:

```
def f(s):
    words = re.split(r'\b(\w+)\b', s)
    ret = ''
    for word in words:
        for char in word:
            if word.isupper():
                ret += chr(ord(c) + 120237)
            elif word.islower():
                ret += chr(ord(c) + 120153)
            else:
                ret += c
    return ret
```

Comment: could it be less bytes if you set a variable to either 120237 or 120153 depending on if it was upper or lower? It looks like it might

Comment: @pfg Indeed, can easily shave off 13 bytes (down to [160](https://tio.run/##bY4xa8MwFITn@Fe8zU8kmCSmFAwZUpLQoW2GZPQiKzJWka3H0zNufr2rlrZTl4O77@CO7tKFoZzbXT173Tc3DbHK8@I9uAF7TfgTyn@hqUzHGPiGRi1xs11vHkpwLUjhog@TZVTWRwuJbMvHXzIS/ZG1UiuQJGyLSN4Jcl43WE9LVTf5KiqlMtdTYAG2s/C9yhZT57yFK482mQWxGwRbdAONgl99@2EsCRzPpyNz4FQiHeP8fcjoNNpr6SDqIWZP55cDvO6vz3DZv10@AQ)).

Comment: @pfg Actually, replacing the map-lambda with (easier to read) comprehensions brings it down to [149 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY4xa8MwEIXn@Ffc5hMpJokphUCHlCR0aJshGb3IioyvyJI4nXHz6121JZ3ee3zf8OJN@uDruXtuZqeH9qohbcuy@gzk8Z6mZwx8RaOWuN6s1o81UAdSUXJhsozKumQhk039dCdjjP9kpRR0gcEAeZC/Lj@dbZWiI0EumxabaamatnxIShU0xMCShVn4ti0WU0/OwoVHm8ciMnnBDsnHUVBl334ZGwUOp@OBOXCWok5p/v1ndP4waOkhaZ@Kl9PbHt53l1c47z7O3w).

Comment: [140](https://tio.run/##Pc4xa8MwEIbhOf4Vt/lEikliSiGQISEpHdpmSEYvsiLjK7IkTmfc/HpXbWnHj/cZvniXPvh67nbN7PTQ3jSkbVlWH4E8mp4x8A2NWuJ6s1o/1kAdSEXJhckyKuuShVw29dNfGWP8LyuloAsMAuSBbZWiI0EumxabaamatnxIv8J8C1EFDTGwZDsL37fFYurJWbjyaPNYRCYv2CH5OAoqpQr7aWwUOJ2fT8yBM4o6pfnnntH5wqClh6R9Kg7n1yO87a8vcNm/X74A)

Comment: [122](https://tio.run/##Jc5Ba8JAEIbhs/kVc8uuSqgGEQQPllp60HrQYy6bdUO2JLvDzITor48xPc7Lw8fgU@oY8qHaF0Nj2vJugHdpmv1FH5StSUW6K6sXq/XHapPPJfPcxN6RmtI6306pQ3wnDVUkEPAByGWMjRdFaVGqol/ookyX/C/sW4hOfIuRZLSD0HOXzPraNw5u1LnxmCH5IKpSPmAn47hO3MM6FDhevo9EkUaEhnmYHrKGHbRGamATOPm8nL7gfLj9wPXwe30B) :-) I'll stop here; quite proud of how golfing it further has made it easier to read. Only in Python!

Comment: [-2](https://tio.run/#%23HY7BisIwFEX3fsXDTRMdHmoRQXAhM8NQkI5o3HWTppFmSJOQvOLM13fawl2dey7c8Eetd/nw7J2CE1SDlV3dSEjHLMMfbxxTbWQ@Nkzx9Xa32e7zFaFJ1r90ZDPa5YcZ9SFMiD99BALjIGpMwRpiMatqVr3WvKqztzQLahKIL0wXfKRRHUI0jtj0gy1FaxKMkQ70r@yC1XAXt6L8AmolgUKPD7xgg1BrKMrrQ4jPD4RirMbJ@3cpzkUJXW/JTNukHWmndMIl58M/) by getting rid of spaces before `for`

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 84 bytes

```
/\b[A-Z]+\b/_(`.
ĵ$&
)T`L`ۮ-܇
/\b[a-z]+\b/_(`.
ĵ$&
)T`l`ں-ۓ
T`ÿ-߿`퟿-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/Xz8mKdpRNypWOyZJP14jQY/ryFYVNS7NkASfhNvrdO@0c4EUJOpWYSrISbi1S/f2ZK6QhMP7de/vT3g7f7/uu4aG//9DMjKLFYAoMU8htSIxtyAnVSE4JMjTz12hJCOxRCFZL18vVM9HL0VPISlVwdMvIDQkxNVFT8ETKAXU4uzvF@Lo6aeQW5pTkgnSW5yaV5Kal5xarAcA) Explanation: Retina is a .NET application and therefore works in UTF-16 internally. Unfortunately as the Math Sans characters aren't in the BMP I can't directly transliterate them because the number of code points differs. Worse, I can't use unpaired surrogates at all. Instead, I shift the appropriate words into characters in the range `0xFF-0x7FF` which conveniently only take two bytes to encode, plus I also prefix them with the `0x135` character. Finally I map that range onto the a range that overlaps the unpaired surrogates, creating valid BMP pairs.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>99</s> <s>114</s> 113 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/\b([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)\b/g,e=>e.replace(/./g,f=>String.fromCodePoint(f.charCodeAt()+120153+(f<'a')*84)))
```

(Thanks to @pfg for pointing out an important flaw in my first solution.)

-1 bytes thanks to @Neil.

**Snippet:**

```js
let f = 

s=>s.replace(/\b([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)\b/g,e=>e.replace(/./g,f=>String.fromCodePoint(f.charCodeAt()+120153+(f<'a')*84)))

d.innerHTML=f('This is an example STRING that c.o.U.L.d. be INPUTTED. It can CONTAIN multiple sentences.');
```

```html
<p id="d">
```

Comment: This only works with the HTML because of the &#, to do it with pure JS you would need to use `String.fromCodePoint(120237)` which would increase the size

Comment: Don't yet grok that, but I'll come back to it later, thanks.

Comment: `let a = s=>s.replace(/\b([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)\b/g,e=>e.replace(/./g,f=>String.fromCodePoint(f.charCodeAt(0)+120153+(f<'a')*84)))` works pure JS but adds many extra bytes

Comment: Ah, I understand!  Daggum.

Comment: Save 1 byte by using `charCodeAt()` without the `0`.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 33 bytes

```
€aγ€g£εÐ.u•1Ù„•*s.l•1Ùm•*+sÇ+çJ}J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UdOaxHObgWT6ocXnth6eoFf6qGGR4eGZjxrmARlaxXo5EH4uiKddfLhd@/Byr1qv//9DMjKLFYAoMU8htSIxtyAnVSE4JMjTz12hJCOxRCFZL18vVM9HL0VPISlVwdMvIDQkxNVFT8ETKAXU4uzvF@Lo6aeQW5pTkgnSW5yaV5Kal5xarAcA)