# Translate English Characters to the Emoji Flag Alphabet

Tags: code-golf, string

### Introduction

Emoji use a particular alphabet for their national flags, which allows one to put two symbols together to create the appropriate flag.

Your challenge, is to transform any uppercase letter into the appropriate Flag Identifier.

This may be much harder for languages that do not innately handle Unicode.
Each symbol is exactly 4 UTF-8 Bytes.

### The Task

Given an input as one or more letters, output the same, with all letters replaced with their flag combinations.

Winner is the answer with the least *Bytes*, giving the tiebreaker to first answer posted.

### Input / Output

Input and Output may use any standard method.
Letters in the input may optionally only support one case, Upper or Lower. Please specify in your answer what case your solution supports.

Your output may, intentionally or otherwise, output flag emoji instead of letter pairs.

### Test Cases

`FR`

`Hello, World!` `, !`

### Rules

- Standard Loopholes Apply
- Standard Input Output allowed
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), however, All the Emoji Letters as provided above can be counted for a single byte each, instead of four. Least Bytes wins!

Comment: Test case number two transforms both cases, do we have to do this?

Comment: As stated, it's not required. It's just to show what would happen if supported.

Comment: bytes should be counted, someone can just pack data into dense Chinese characters and win.

Comment: I'll change it to count bytes, but let the flag letter emoji count as only one byte, to keep with the initial intention.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60443/s%E1%B4%8D%E1%B4%80%CA%9F%CA%9F-c%E1%B4%80%E1%B4%98%EA%9C%B1-c%E1%B4%8F%C9%B4%E1%B4%A0%E1%B4%87%CA%80%E1%B4%9B%E1%B4%87%CA%80)?

Comment: In the initial alphabet, by browser shows DE as a flag... Maybe add some sort of separator between the letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Retina - <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Supports uppercase.

I don't really know retina, so I'm not sure the question mark diamonds show up because of TIO limitations or because I did something wrong, if its the latter, please leave a comment.

```
T`L`-
```

[Try it online here](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGBMYPCfh6Yt8J-Hvw&input=RlIKSGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQ).

Comment: The obvious solution sometimes is also the best.

Comment:  and  are 4 bytes each so it's actually 13 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>18</s> 16 bytes

Supports lowercase.

```
XzGsCMrF+BC\26
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=XzGsCMrF%2BBC%5C%F0%9F%87%A626&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=FR%0AHello%2C+World%21&debug=0).

Comment: Doesn't convert FR for me on online link?

Comment: @Downgoat FR is all uppercase, and this answer only supports lowercase

Comment: @ATaco did not see that will be golfing that

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

*Ties [Steffan's Vyxal answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/248378) for #1.*

```
A""ÇŸç‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fUenD/PZlQLxf6XD70R2Hlz9qWPj/f0ZqTk6@jkJ5flFOiiIA) Supports lowercase only.

Comment: The Retina answer is 7 bytes if we still want to go by the rules the *challenge* says: `All the Emoji Letters as provided above can be counted for a single byte each, instead of four. Least Bytes wins!` However, the Retina answer is broken; it displays question marks and not the correct characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
Cʀ»ƛ⁽ṗ»*+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJDOiIsIkPKgMK7xpvigb3huZfCuyorIiwiQ+G5hSIsIkhFTExPLCBXT1JMRCEiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua 5.3, 76 bytes

Lua 5.3 newly has a UTF-8 manipulation library, which is useful in this case.

Lowercase only

```
print(arg[1]:gsub("%l",function(c)return utf8.char(c:byte()+127365)end).."")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 75 bytes

```
(s:String)=>s.flatMap(c=>if(c.isLetter)Seq(55356,c+56741)else Seq(c))
```

Explanation:

```
(s:String)=>             //define an anonymous function taking a string
  s.flatMap(c=>            //map each char...
    if(c.isLetter)           //if it's a letter
      Seq(55356,c+56741)       //...to a sequence of 55356 and c+56741, this is the target char in UTF16 encoding as a surrogate pair
    else                     //else
      Seq(c)                   //..to a sequence of c
  )                        //and flatten
```

Only works for uppercase.
This returns a the output as sequence of integers in UTF16.

Answer (score 1):

## x86-64, 17 bytes

Takes input as UTF-32LE string in `rsi`, and outputs in the same format to a buffer at `rdi`, and code point count in `rcx`. Only works for uppercase letters. This can be linked to C code with the function signature `void f(int *output,int *input,int dummy,int count);`. The dummy variable is just to put the count in the `rcx` register.

`fff10100` is the UTF-32LE encoding for , and so only costs one byte.

```
ad 50 5a 2c 41 2c 19 8d 80 fff10100 0f 47 c2 ab e2 ed c3
```

Or, in assembly:

```
   0:   ad                      lodsd
   1:   50                      push   rax
   2:   5a                      pop    rdx
   3:   2c 41                   sub    al,0x41
   5:   2c 19                   sub    al,0x19
   7:   8d 80 ff f1 01 00       lea    eax,[rax+0x1f1ff]
   d:   0f 47 c2                cmova  eax,edx
  10:   ab                      stosd
  11:   e2 ed                   loop   0
  13:   c3                      ret
```

Uses the string manipulation instruction `lodsd` to load one code point into `eax`, checks if it's a capital letter using two successive subtractions, and adds the appropriate value to convert it to a flag if it is. Otherwise, it uses the conditional move `cmova` to restore its original ascii value. Finally, it uses `stosd` to put a code point in the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>125</s> 111 bytes

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{for(v++;c=**v;putchar(" Ee"[c]+*(*v)++))c=!isalpha(c)-~!islower(c),c%3&&printf(L"\x879ff0");}
```

*-14 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcnRCsIgFADQX9mExr26QdBDheyxt/6gepCbpuCm2HJB1K/b9ng41D2IShmUG4HajGRV4jzLjwkJshCS@pXxNa0DrDppdqGb4MAzCoFIfe2eykergLD7LfBh1mlBS5td08TkxsnAmV3fh/3RmC1D@S2lWO19aKs5JH@v/w)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
e€ØA×“¢®Ƒ’+OỌ
```

Supports only uppercase letters.

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=ZeKCrMOYQcOX4oCcwqLCrsaR4oCZK0_hu4w&input=&args=SEVMTE8sIFdPUkxEIQ)

### Explanation

```
e€ØA×“¢®Ƒ’+OỌ  Input: string S
e€             Test if each char in S is an element of
  ØA             the uppercase alphabet 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    ×          Multiply by
     “¢®Ƒ’       The codepoints of '¢®Ƒ' as a base 250 integer
                 This forms 127397
          +    Vectorized add with
           O     The codepoints of each char in S
            Ọ  Convert back to char from codepoints
               Return and print implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 101 Bytes

supports both replace 64 with 96 to support only lowercase. input only ascii characters allowed

```
foreach(str_split($argv[1])as$c)echo($o=ord($c))>64&&$o%32<27?hex2bin("f09f87".dechex($o%32+165)):$c;
```

PHP, 112 Bytes

supports both remove i as modifier in the regex to support only lowercase

```
<?=preg_replace_callback("#[a-z]#i",function($t){return hex2bin("f09f87".dechex(ord($t[0])%32+165));},$argv[1]);
```

first version 205 Bytes

```
<?=preg_replace_callback("#[a-z]#i",function($t){return substr("",(ord($t[0])%32-1)*4,4);},$argv[1]);
```

The version with `mb_substr` is one Byte longer

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]/g,c=>String.fromCodePoint(c.codePointAt()+127397))
;
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><div id=o>
```

Accepts upper case only. Mixed case version for 73 bytes:

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]/gi,c=>String.fromCodePoint(c.codePointAt()+5|127392))
;
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><div id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 68 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join(chr(x+127397*(64<x<91))for x in map(ord,s.upper()))
```

Usage (when assigned to `f`):

```python
print(f("Hello, World!"))
print(f("A B C - X Y Z"))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, 17 bytes

Counting the letter symbols as one byte each, per OP. Works with uppercase letters.

```ruby
$_.tr!"A-Z","-"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6BUuyCpaUlaboW21Xi9UqKFJUcdaOUdJQ-zG9fpgsk9itBZKGKFmxwC-LycPXx8ddRCPcP8nFRhIgDAA)