# Generate Tiny Text

Tags: code-golf, string, unicode

### Challenge

Your program needs to take an input of a string, where the string has only letters, no special characters, no numbers, and no accents (they look all weird).

Then, your program should output a [superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subscript_and_superscript) version.

### Example

**Input:** hello world

**Output:** ʰᵉᶫᶫᵒ ʷᵒʳᶫᵈ

### Test Cases

```
hello - ʰᵉᶫᶫᵒ
code - ᶜᵒᵈᵉ
golf - ᵍᵒᶫᶠ
asdf - ᵃˢᵈᶠ
qwerty - ᑫʷᵉʳᵗʸ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz - ᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰᶦʲᵏᶫᵐᶰᵒᵖᑫʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ
```

### Help

If you need help understanding check out this website, it's a translator:
http://txtn.us/tiny-text

### Code Golf

This is a code golf, so the shortest code wins!

Good luck!

### Edits

**Edit #1:** There will be no caps, since I just realized they look weird.

Comment: Will they be all lowercase?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60443/sᴍᴀʟʟ-cᴀᴘꜱ-cᴏɴᴠᴇʀᴛᴇʀ)

Comment: @BetaDecay They're related but this is superscript

Comment: @BetaDecay Oops, sorry.

Comment: @ASCII-only I changed my mind, see edit, all lowercase.

Comment: `tr` is `tr`, and changing the second argument from small caps to superscript doesn't make a fundamentally different question.

Comment: "output superscript version" - output where? If I am not mistaken, there is no even such a thing as unicode latin superscript letters. If so this does not make sense for text output, and should be tagged `graphical-output` or `browser`.

Comment: Also in your examples I see letters I, L, N, as caps and q as normal size, so it does not work in Firefox.

Comment: @MikhailV it's unicode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Comment: yes that's what I am saying " the Unicode standard contains superscript and subscript versions of a **subset** of Latin ... these characters come from different ranges, they may not be of the same size and position, depending on the typeface" So there is no standard latin superscript in unicode.

Comment: @MikhailV but it's still in unicode

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 10 bytes

```
s=>s.sup()
```

> It should be noted that the [`sup()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/sup) has been deprecated so this solution may not work in all browsers nor is it guaranteed to continue working in future releases of browsers that do currently support it. Tested and confirmed to work in Chrome v58.

---

### Try it

```js
f=
s=>s.sup()
o.innerHTML=(i.value="Hello!")+": "+f(i.value)
oninput=_=>o.innerHTML=i.value+": "+f(i.value)
```

```css
*{font-family:arial,sans-serif}
```

```html
<input id=i><p id=o>
```

Comment: Can you add a code snippet try me thing?

Comment: @NoahCristino, Snippet added.

Comment: @Shaggy That's weird, when I converted something like: CAPSLOCK@^&@^& with the website, I get: ᶜᴬᴾˢᴸᴼᶜᴷ@^﹠@^﹠, but with your it works right.

Comment: @Shaggy Yeah, that's probably it

Comment: Deprecated, but still works with all major browsers so gets my vote:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/sup

Comment: @RickHitchcock: Yep, was editing that point into my answer as you were commenting.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP+HTML, 17 Bytes

```
<sup><?=$_GET[0];
```

Comment: Doesn't this still display normal characters, in a superscript size and position?

Comment: `<sup><?=$_GET[0];`

Comment: @L3viathan Yes and the input is limited to letters

Comment: How is it limited to letters?

Comment: @Shaggy The OP says Your program needs to take an input of a string, where the string has only letters, no special characters, no numbers, and no accents (they look all weird).

Comment: Ah, I thought you were implying that your code stripped out non-letter characters - I couldn't see how it was possibly doing that! :D

Comment: @JörgHülsermann The input is letters, but the output is (in my understanding) supposed to _be_ superscript characters (e.g. U+1D43 for a), not just look like them.

Comment: @Shaggy Yes it do the same that your JS answer do

Comment: @L3viathan If your understanding is right there are two other invalid answers from Shaggy and Kevin Cruijssen

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
#~Style~Tiny&
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8 (AWT / Swing), 79 bytes

```java
s->new java.awt.Frame(){{add(new javax.swing.JLabel("<html><sup>"+s));show();}}
```

Unfortunately there is no reliable online compiler available for Java GUI, so no TIO-link.

## Java 8 (Console), <s>123</s> 117 bytes

```java
s->{for(int x:s.toCharArray())System.out.print("ᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰᶦʲᵏᶫᵐᶰᵒᵖᑫʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ".charAt(x-97));}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jZC9TsNADMf3PoWV6TI0K4IKJMRMl46I4Xr5aCC9C3eXklBlYgAGxMcASDAgkFi6VKALSLxB@hR@kpCETEwslmz/bf9/ZhFVCnZpyOc9gJBrT/qUeTBsUoCZCF1gZKRlyANQ9qCu5r06KE11yGAIHDahUv2tuS8kqech3VCOFjsTKrelpBmx7VGmtDd1RKKduN6jiYXmFM0ZFk9oztFcYPGM5rJcYvFWvqO5wmKB5hqLJZpbNHd4syg/Vi9o7tE8oHksP1ev5RcW35bDmjOapP31Ndse5FXjL07GUW2tc9gSTGu@DmJvH6j9C8cdRiztKW21XAB/jUacdJ1WyoTrBSLy/ymnY@Z6fjAJDw6jKRfxkVQ6mR2n2YnV/TGvfgA)

Comment: Do you need the `<html>` tag?

Comment: @Shaggy Unfortunately yes, I've already tried without it when I posted the answer. Without it just outputs `<sup>sometext` literally. It will probably enable html if it sees the `<html>` text in the `JLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 75 bytes (30 chars)

```
XwG"ᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰᶦʲᵏᶫᵐᶰᵒᵖᑫʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=XwG%22%E1%B5%83%E1%B5%87%E1%B6%9C%E1%B5%88%E1%B5%89%E1%B6%A0%E1%B5%8D%CA%B0%E1%B6%A6%CA%B2%E1%B5%8F%E1%B6%AB%E1%B5%90%E1%B6%B0%E1%B5%92%E1%B5%96%E1%91%AB%CA%B3%CB%A2%E1%B5%97%E1%B5%98%E1%B5%9B%CA%B7%CB%A3%CA%B8%E1%B6%BB&input=hello%2C+world%21&debug=0)